# Word Press Static page full height at home page for mobile

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want the site to be 1 page, with the footer and everything and no need to scroll down,
the mobile view of the site always show scroll bar on small devices screen but looks great on large screen phones like onepls6 or iphone8+ ...

```
@ media only screen and (max-width: 460px)
{
   .header-image 
    {
       height: 458px;
    }
}
```

if I made the height like less, it will show well on small devices, but, I got a white page under the footer on large screen mobile devices

Comment: add picture showing difference

Comment: Is the site live, can you provide a link? Why not make a sticky footer that sticks to the bottom of the screen if the screen is too long?

Comment: Hi Nick, this is the link, still working on it
http://alaab.myartsonline.com

the problem i am facing, is that i need to have 1 page contain everything i have on this homepage, i only have a cover and a footer, the problem is with smaller screen the scroll appears and with the big cscreen a blank white space appears at the end of the page, 
i know it can be happen but i cant catch the way :(
hope yopu can help me with that 
Big thanks

Comment: this scroll issue i mean on all devices PCs and mobiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#page {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.header-image {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi Evil, 
it didnt work :(, make the screen 2 pages on mobile and have to scroll.
the other issue i am facing is, i want to have all th econtet on 1 page and no scroll nedded, i only have a cover and a footer, and on small screen, the scroll, appears.
any CSS or something can fix that ?

Comment: this scroll issue i mean on all devices PCs and mobiles

Comment: Since you have shared your site, i will change the answer a little bit.

Comment: Hello man, it works man it works, you are amazing Big thanks to you :) 
one more quastion, shall i remove all the custome Css i made for the screen size like this one 
@media (min-width: 1400px) and (max-width: 1950px){
.header-image {
    height: 700px;
}}

and like the mobile version ?

Comment: # last thing :) and i am so sorry for lots of issue, 
i have used this css keep the nav menu at 1 line even when the screen gets smaller, is it ok ?

@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1320px){
.main-navigation a{
 font-size: 1.04vw;
 font-weight:bold;}}

Comment: Probably yes, because it will fit all remaining space independently of screen height.

Comment: Hmm..., I would use `flex` on `.main-navigation ul` to prevent items from wrapping.

Comment: man the display: flex, works only on PC version 
but the mobile still have it with scroll. 

shall i use the old way, like this ?


@media only screen and (max-width: 460px){
.header-image {
    height: 458px;
}}

or there is a better way, that makes it like desktop to show same flex on all mobile phones

Comment: Strange, but i have no scroll on mobile version.

Comment: Man you are amazing person and thank you for reply to my quastions, 
#1, i have tired the .main-navigation ul and disply flex, the menu wraped under each other and the logo went all the way to left pushing the menu to the right, you think i should something to it ?, the logo is under site Branding

2#can i use the first fix you give me for removing the scroll  #page  only for homepage, as its little bit beak the padding of the other pages.

Comment: Try `min-hieght: 100vh` instead of `hieght: 100vh`.

Comment: What about navigation. You need to slightly change markup. It would be nice if you can share your header using [codepen](https://codepen.io) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net), so I can edit it to satisfy your needs.

Comment: Hi Man and thank you so much again for following and you help :)

i have never done this theme header share, but what i do is, i went to them editor and copy the header and post it at codepen at the following link 

codepen.io/AlexB1/post/theme-header

Comment: i found this main.js also if it helps ?

codepen.io/AlexB1/post/main-js

Comment: Did `min-height: 100vh` help?

Comment: What about question #3, i can not see any strange behavior, everything looks great. Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: this is the old soulotion i used, before the flex option you give me, 

@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1320px){
.main-navigation a{
 font-size: 1vw;
 font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing: 0px;
}
}

and ,container{width:100%}

this soultoutins makes it alright but break at some points to 2 lines, and make some issues with the theme in general

Comment: Hey Man, 
i fix it this way, what do u think is it a noob fix ?


.site-branding.col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12 {
  width: 150px;
 left:30px;

}

#primary-menu.menu {
  position: relative;

}
#primary-menu.menu {
float:left;
  width: 69em;
}

@media (min-width: 925px) and (max-width: 1250px){.main-navigation a{font-size:86%;
 font-weight:600;}}


.site-header .container {
  width: 100%;
}